# OK, I'll bite: Why was my post closed as unlikely to ever help any future visitors?

Tags: discussion

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39209/what-other-categorical-synonyms-could-represent-published-content-or-articles-o

> an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

I didn't notice prohibition to computer topic in the FAQ (after it was closed :) But, this is your sandbox folks. If you see EL&U as existing in the narrow-band range of dictionary reading and interpretation, I agree this would be a simple topic. However, it should be obvious I'm not attempting to find some here-to-for undiscovered term that every computer software operating system developer has not thought of.

I was rather looking forward towards creative examples, and possibly terms others use to manage the influx of documents collecting on their hard drives. Or am I so out of touch, and everyone is tagging files, making a generic folder unnecessary?

But "not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet" is ridiculous. Robusto 初夢, drɱ65 δ, Mitch, aedia λ, or kiamlaluno should speak up to explain their **opinion**.

Comment: Can you do us the favor of putting a link to the question here?

Comment: @Mitch: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39209/what-other-categorical-synonyms-could-represent-published-content-or-articles-o

Comment: I voted to close for generally the same reasons as Mitch explains below. We aren't the same as a forum; we like to make sure questions and answers will help future visitors too. Sometimes, we even close good questions just because we're not suited to answer them here. You can always try to improve your closed question to make it a better fit for the site.

Comment: [Related](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15538/2085).

Answer (score 8):

Since you ask explicitly, I'll be honest. And I think this will help others who find their question closed as too localized, not constructive or not a real question. The particular question was closed because it was not good, and for me, for many reasons. You can only pick one reason when voting to close, and we all happened to choose 'too localized'. But here are the reasons I thought it was closeable (including 'too localized'):

- your question is incoherent. In fact it is difficult to find an explicit question there. One can read between the lines, and figure something out but it is not clear.
- The reason it is considered too localized by us has nothing to do with 'computer topics'. There is some leeway for asking about technical terminology, but if the question is too technical it might be considered off-topic and either closed for that reason or migrated to the nearest SE site (or recommended to some other QA site).
- Now to what you are really asking. The question seems to be some general advice about what -you- would like to name your directories. How can that possibly be helpful to someone else? And why would someone come here to see how to name their directories? What do you name your kids so you don't confuse them? (for the latter, people ask people all the time, but you don't go to a language QA site for it).

You might be able to reword your question to be more generally applicable, more coherent, and more explicit, but then I think it would turn into a question about user interface (e.g. "What do some computer systems use to distinguish personal documents?") and so would be off-topic here but very much on-topic for other SE sites.

Comment: +1: This was more or less my line of reasoning as well.

Comment: I name my sons Bobby and Dan; yet, I keep calling Bobby the one I was supposed to call Dan. Uhmmm… What was the question, by the way?

Answer (score 2):

The problems I can see with the question are that:

- How you name the directories of your hard disk probably depends from which files you have. I would think that you don't call a directory "Butterfly pictures" if you don't have butterfly pictures; you could choose that name for not making clear what the content is, but in that case, you could choose any random name.
- The answers to that question would be arbitrary, as there aren't any rule you are forced to follow while choosing the name of a directory. Probably you would get different answers about which name to use, as every user has a preferred schema to use for choosing the name to give to directories.
- There is no relation between the name of a directory, and English grammar; you could use a name such as "ABBDDE," "Le mie fotografie," or a random sequence of letters and numbers.

In the first case, if you were more detailed with the type of files you have on your hard disk, the question would be even more localized.

In the second case, as every answer would be equally valid, the question would be a poll, which is the kind of question that are not welcome anymore. If some very old questions are polls (where by very old I mean questions asked during the beta phase), now such questions are not welcome anymore, considering also that Community Wiki questions have a different meaning, now that every user can edit every question (although users with a reputation lower than 2000 need somebody who review their edit).

In the third case, the question is not even about the English language and its usage. The question is similar to the questions about the name to give to a function; the difference is that some programming languages some words are reserved, and they cannot be used as function name. In both the cases, there isn't any relationship between the chosen name and English grammar; in the case of function names is more a matter of the programming language grammar.

Answer (score -2):

I wrote in this meta post, and I'll say it again, I'm not going to argue about what you will or will not allow on your site.

This is simply a creative language question. In the one answer I did get before it was closed, the author did understand the question, and provided a very accurate, though academically taxonomic, answer. Frankly I'm surprised you felt the need to censor the question. I find most social forum questions which do not hit the mark are simply ignored. What better way to prove your point then to let the question "die on the vine" so to speak. I find it intolerant on your behalf.

As to the question if this is completely arbitrary. That's simply a put down. There is no comparison between a "proper noun" and a "creative name" for a taxonomic category. If anything I should have thought it fun for any geek who ever wanted to customize someone else's desktop with their visual wallpaper. Though here a good name for what I describe might result in my naming the folder of collected PDFs and wot-wot docs, "TotallySuperAwsomeLettersStrungTogether". And a name *that* long would bungup the compact list view of the Explorer window.

But its your sandbox. I'll simply take my toys and go home...

Comment: You may want to read through [this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1665/closing-is-not-bad)

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but this seems to be a similar situation as [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39494/word-order-and-meaning-which-is-correct-for-this-notice)--it is an interesting question, but it may not help future visitors.